# flot display the date in flot based on timestamp

Tags: jquery, date, graph, flot

Does anyone know how to display the date in flot based on timestamp

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var d1 = [
[1262818800,100],[1262732400,100],[1262646000,100],[1262559600,100],[1262473200,100],[1262386800,100],[1262300400,100],[1262214000,100],[1262127600,100],[1262041200,100],[1261954800,100],[1261868400,100],[1261782000,100],[1261695600,100],[1261609200,100],[1261522800,95],[1261436400,110],[1261350000,110],[1261263600,110],[1261177200,100];

var d2 = [
[1262818800,23],[1262732400,23],[1262646000,23],[1262559600,23],[1262473200,23],[1262386800,23],[1262300400,25],[1262214000,25],[1262127600,25],[1262041200,25],[1261954800,25],[1261868400,25],[1261782000,25],[1261695600,25],[1261609200,25],[1261522800,25],[1261436400,10],[1261350000,10],[1261263600,10],[1261177200,10]

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [{data:d1,lines:{show: true},label:"Mountain"},{data:d2,lines:{show: true},label:"Valley"}],{yaxis: {label:"cm"}},
{xaxis: {mode:"time"
}}
);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Mark, did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: up for showing me the right data format

Answer (score 22):

I guess all you need to do is to multiply the timestamp (which look like unix timestamps) by 1000.

Unix timestamp tracks time as a running total of seconds starting from January 1st, 1970. While javascript timestamps measure milliseconds. So just multiply by 1000 and you should be fine

Comment: You should accept this, it's the correct answer. After you have multiplied by 1000, you may also need to subtract by your time relative to UTC, for example EST is - 18000. So to get the correct time, for me it would be; (timestamp * 1000) - 18000

Answer (score 4):

Try defining the 'timeformat' attribute, and define the pattern that flot will use to format the millisecond value.

```
xaxis:{
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%M:%S"
},
```

Comment: I need you for some jquery tasks if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
    var options = {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true },
    xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",   minTickSize: [1, "day"]}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and I think we both used the same bad Flot example.  The signature is:

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options)
```

And your code is doing something like

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, xoptions, yoptions)
```

So to fix it, just do this instead:

```
$.plot(
    $("#placeholder"), 
    [{data:d1,lines:{show: true},label:"Mountain"},{data:d2,lines:{show:true},label:"Valley"}],
    {yaxis: {label:"cm"}, xaxis: {mode:"time"}}
);
```