# Using dates in jQuery Flot display

Tags: jquery, date, timestamp, flot

I'm trying to use Flot to plot a graph with dates.  I've followed the advice on this string: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020864/flot-display-the-date-in-flot-based-on-timestamp) but it doesn't seem to work for me. Here is my modified JavaScript (from that other question):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d1 = [[1262818800,100],[1262732400,100],[1262646000,100]]; 

    var d2 = [[1262818800,23],[1262732400,23],[1262646000,23]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{data:d1,lines:{show: true},label:"Mountain"},{data:d2,lines:{show: true},label:"Valley"}],{yaxis: {label:"cm"}},
    {xaxis: 
      {mode:"time",
      timeformat: "%M:%S"
 }
    });

});
```

I get a graph, but it doesn't convert the x-axis into dates, and the values on the x-axis don't even line up with what I've got in the data variables.  I've even tried multiplying each datapoint by 1000 to convert to Javascript timestamps, but that didn't help either.  I've also tried the following timeformat variables, in case that was the problem:

```
"%M:%S", "%H:%S", "%y,%m,%d"
```

But no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an exapmle where dates are working: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html maybe start with this code and try to modify it for your needs

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It was helpful to work backward from there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should multiply to 1000 and use:

```
xaxis: {
      mode: "time"
  }
```

I tested this way.
I can post the full code if you need.

This is a little italian post about using flot to measure my baby's height and weight:

- http://www.bits4beats.it/sviluppo-web/controllare-il-peso-del-bimbo-tramite-html-e-jquery/

The project code is downloadable from [here](http://www.bits4beats.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/peso_giulia.zip).

Unzip it and open the file *peso_giulia.html* . Here you can find the d3 series.

You can replace the line

```
,[(new Date("2009/12/29")).getTime(),67]
```

with the timestamp version

```
,[(1282688250 * 1000), 100]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had to do one more thing--there were too many '{' and '}' in the so I don't think the options for the x-axis were even processing properly.  But I would still appreciate seeing your code.