# flot not graphing my data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, flot

I have the following array:

```
var open_emails = [];
open_emails = [["2012-04-21", 5], ["2012-04-20", 1], ["2012-04-22", 4]];
```

When I put it into jquery.flot it does not graph and I don't know why:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [open_emails]);
```

How can I graph this data showing the dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open_emails = [["2012-04-21", 5], ["2012-04-20", 1], ["2012-04-22", 4]];
I think the date is String type, so it cannot plot as value.

you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560960/using-dates-in-jquery-flot-display)

Comment: Yes I had to convert the date to a time object in milliseconds. Thank for putting me on the right path