# x-axis timestamp graph js

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

I am trying to create a graph where the x-axis consists of timestamp (date) and Y axis data.
I am having a problem with the X axis, 
What can I edit the code so that it will have a template like "date(Y-m-d)".

**Please i need help I searched a lot and did not find anything**

```
$a=[1419717600000,0],[1419631200000,1000],[1419544800000,1000],[1419458400000,6000],[1419372000000,2000],[1419285600000,0],[1419199200000,0],[1419112800000,0],[1419026400000,0],[1418940000000,0],[1418853600000,0];

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {


    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),[ 


        { data: [$a], color: 'black'}

    ], {

        series: {
            lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: 'rgba(143, 198, 242, 0)' },
            points: { show: true}
        },
        grid: { 
            color: 'transparent',
            margin: 10
        },xaxis: {
      mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%Y/%m/%d"
  },
        xaxis: { 
          color: 'white',
            font: { color: 'white', family: 'sans-serif', size: 11}
        },
        yaxis: { 
            color: 'white',
            font: { color: 'white', family: 'sans-serif', size: 11}
        }
    });
});



});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying your timestamp value by 1000, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022359/3966682). (Too low rep to comment)